# How to link own external modules in a Notebook with pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a main IPython notebook in which I have the code that executes different tasks.

I need to import an own module in form of .py file in the notebook, like this way:

```py
from custom_module import function
```

We can suppose `custom_module.py` is:

```py
def function(x): 
    print(x)
```

As I understand from the documentation, what I need to do is writting the following:

```shell
$pyspark --py-files custom_module.py
```

The command above works only when the module is in same folder of ipynb but, what is I have module .py file in other directory?

I tried code below with no good results. No module found.

```
$pyspark --py-files /home/username/desktop/test/custom_module.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically this would work on the clients but not on the driver.
One way that I found of doing it was by making sure the directory where custom_module is located on the driver is in the PYTHONPATH.